# How to yield all errors (failures) with Either

Tags: scala, error-handling, either

I am completely new to Scala. AFAIK, `Either` encapsulate failure handling allowing chain operations without writing boilerplate code repeatedly. It allows also circuit break the continuation of execution. But this may not always what I want. e.g. for the following code, if both `name` and `age` are invalid, the `makePerson` function **will not return both errors**.

Can you guys please suggest a way?

```scala
case class Person(name: Name, age: Age)
sealed class Name(val value: String)
sealed class Age(val value: Int)

case class Person(name: Name, age: Age){

}
sealed class Name(val value: String)
sealed class Age(val value: Int)

object Person{
    def makeName(name: String): Either[String, Name] = {
        if (name == "" || name == null) Left("Name is empty.") else Right(new Name(name))
    }

    def makeAge(age: Int): Either[String, Age] = {
        if (age < 0) Left("Age is out of range.") else Right(new Age(age))
    }

    def makePerson(name: String, age: Int): Either[String, Person] = {
        mkName(name).map2(mkAge(age))(Person(_, _))
    }
}
```

```scala
    def map2[EE >: E, B, C](b: Either[EE, B])(f: (A, B) => C): Either[EE, C] = {
            val func = (aa: A) => b.map(bb => f(aa, bb))
            this.flatMap(func)
    }


    def flatMap[EE >: E, B](f: A => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B] = this match {
        case Left(e) => Left(e)
        case Right(a) => f(a)
    }
```

Comment: Technically speaking, you can not. At least not using standard methods. You may write all the boiler plate to return a `Either[List[Error], Value]`. However, if you are open to other alternatives, I would suggest you using [**cats**](https://github.com/typelevel/cats). You have two options, one is to use [`Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) instead of `Either` _(which was designed for this1)_, the other one would be to use the [`Parallel`](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2019/09/11/why-parallel/) instance of `Either` _(which in turn uses `Validated` under the hood)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank yous so much. I will definitely look into these what you suggested me

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You should put that as an answer

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez works exclusively in the comments section :)

Comment: @Lasf I sometimes supplement his comment with an example and unfairly collect his upvotes for which I apologise.

Comment: @MarioGalic symbiosis!

Answer (score 7):

Here are examples of error accumulation using `Validated` and `Parallel` as suggested by @Luis:

### `Validated`

```
import cats.data.ValidatedNec
import cats.implicits._

case class Person(name: Name, age: Age)
case class Name(value: String)
case class Age(value: Int)

object validatedPerson extends App {
  private def validateName(name: String): ValidatedNec[String, Name] =
    if (name == "" || name == null) "Name is empty.".invalidNec else Name(name).validNec

  private def validateAge(age: Int): ValidatedNec[String, Age] =
    if (age < 0) "Age is out of range.".invalidNec else Age(age).validNec


  def validatePerson(name: String, age: Int): ValidatedNec[String, Person] = {
    (validateName(name), validateAge(age)).mapN(Person)
  }

  println(validatePerson(name = "Joe", age = 21))
  println(validatePerson(name = "", age = -42))
}
```

which outputs

```
Valid(Person(Name(Joe),Age(21)))
Invalid(Chain(Name is empty., Age is out of range.))
```

where we see in the `Invalid` case all the errors were accumulated.

### `Parallel`

```
import cats.data.{EitherNel, NonEmptyList}
import cats.instances.parallel._
import cats.syntax.parallel._

object parValidatedPerson extends App {
  private def validateName(name: String): EitherNel[String, Name] =
    if (name == "" || name == null) Left(NonEmptyList.one("Name is empty.")) else Right(Name(name))

  private def validateAge(age: Int): EitherNel[String, Age] =
    if (age < 0) Left(NonEmptyList.one("Age is out of range.")) else Right(Age(age))


  def validatePerson(name: String, age: Int): Either[NonEmptyList[String], Person] = {
    (validateName(name), validateAge(age)).parTupled.map(Person.tupled)
  }

  println(validatePerson(name = "Joe", age = 21))
  println(validatePerson(name = "", age = -42))
}
```

which outputs

```
Right(Person(Name(Joe),Age(21)))
Left(NonEmptyList(Name is empty., Age is out of range.))
```

where we see in the `Left` case all the errors were accumulated.

Comment: You know, you should not feel bad by providing good quality answers ;) - Most of the time I can not write a complete answer, either because on phone, or no time. But, as I just want to help, I try to write useful comments. So I am really happy people find they valuable and that other people can provide good answers! - BTW, right now I do not really care about the points, it was cool to reach my first 1K at that time I was also the first of the period, I remember I posted on all my social media! But, soon after that, I realized I really did not care about the points, but the feeling of helping.